# PhpStorm - How can I avoid creating the .idea folder?

Tags: phpstorm

I don't want PhpStorm to create an .idea folder. Is this possible?

I'm working in a new environment where I pretty much MUST figure out a way to remove them or I have to change IDE, which I really don't want to do.

Can't PhpStorm store the project files and settings in its own directory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I don't want PhpStorm to create an .idea folder. Is this possible?

No, but workaround is very simple and described in the actual ticket body: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343 :

> **WORKAROUND:** Actually you can do it for a long time - but only manually. Just create a new project anywhere where you want to store your project data, then go to "Settings | Directories" and detach its dir and attach your project root folder.
>   Just remember to open this folder instead of actual one next time.

Comment: Can we do the same thing with an existing project?

Comment: @A.L I have not done it myself (have no need), but I see reason why not -- you will have to copy all files in that different location first, open that new project, do the content root manipulations. After closing project you can remove `.idea` from original project and content root files from new location. But you will have to double check the paths (to your tools etc) after doing such move -- they may not be correct. I personally would just create brand new project and then copy certain config files between them -- there is no much to reconfigure.

Comment: I was confused by the *detach* and *attach* words because they are not mentioned in the PhpStorm toolbox. I used your method: creating a new project then copying the source code in the main directory and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe, as an alternative, if you use a VCS, you can add `.idea` to your VCS ignore list? For example, for Mercurial it is called `.hgignore` and for Git - `.gitignore`.

Comment: I would if I could. But we're working in a remote codebase so I don't actually have the code locally, which means PhpStorm creates the .idea folder in on the server.