# PhpStorm Project Settings per User?

Tags: settings, phpstorm

In my company 3 developers use PhpStorm for developing WebApps.
Everyone needs to open (not simultaneously) a project an other user created from time to time.

Let's say user A uses a deployment server named server A and user B uses server b.
User A created the project in the deployment.xml server A is saved.
Now user B needs to open the project and creates server B. Now server B is saved in deployment.xml
If user A want to reopen the project again, he has to set the server back to server A.
Same goes for the  workspace.xml.

My question is if it possible to use different project settings for user A and user B?
If it is possible what do I need to change in my settings?
If not how can 3 users work together (no VCS)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the three devs opening this project from network attached storage? Be aware that some features and performance are reduced when not running on a local native filesystem. Do the devs need to share any PhpStorm settings at all?

Comment: Yes they are opening the project via a network share.
It does not matter whether they can share other PhpStorm settings or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where no settings are to be shared between developers, only the project files, PhpStorm accepts reading project files from a directory outside of the classical 'project directory'. Here is one approach to that; each developer is to:

- Create and open a new empty project from PhpStorm, in a folder on the local hard drive. Only project settings will be stored here.
- Open the Settings dialog, choose 'Directories' from the left pane, then click 'Add Content Root' (at the top of the rightmost pane).
- Choose the folder on the network share that contains the project files.
- Remove the original 'content root' corresponding to the project settings folder on the local hard drive.

Each developer can now open their locally created directory in PhpStorm, and any files opened/created will exist on the shared folder.

A related question: [PhpStorm - How can I avoid creating the .idea folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002665/phpstorm-how-can-i-avoid-creating-the-idea-folder)

Please note that working with files that are not on a local filesystem, especially when they are editable by multiple developers, is not recommended. Even for small projects, storing a Git repository on the network share, with each developer `git pull`ing when beginning work and `git push`ing when done, is a small investment that will pay large dividends. Here is a good introduction: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/, but the key command is `git init --bare reponame` in the setup phase.